# javascript connecting to another instance of browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6, hta

I am making a hta application, which reads data from textboxes (entered by user) of its own window and updates this data in another web browser window (session based, and already opened), how do I connect with other browser window using javascript.

System : client based machine, IE v6

with regards

Comment: @MikeRobinson - It's obviously a job requirement. Be nice.

Comment: @JosephSilber Meant as a joke, I have changed it to more practical advice though

Comment: both browser windows are on the same machine, and both are IE? Does one window open the other window as a popup? If so, this is really ez.

Comment: So, this other window, is it also a HTA?

Comment: no other windows is not HTA, but a web page

Comment: If pages are not in the same domain, I'm afraid there's no way to achieve this with IE6. Though `showModelessDialog()` maybe worth of try.

Comment: Using SHDOCVW library, I could do this in VBA, but somehow its not working with VBscript (inside HTA), so I thought doing this with javascript.
But again ActivexObject creation fails with Javascript.
eg. var obj = new ActiveXObject('Shdocvw.ShellWindows')
eg. var obj = new ActiveXObject('Shdocvw.InternetExplorer') works, but it of no use to grab handle/object of already opened window.